# How do you calculate the modulo of a high-raised number?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

I need some help with this problem:

$$439^{233} \mod 713$$

I can't calculate $439^{223}$ since it's a very big number, there must be a way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: See [How do I compute $a^b\,\bmod c$ by hand?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/how-do-i-compute-ab-bmod-c-by-hand)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compute $a^b\,\bmod c$ by hand?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/how-do-i-compute-ab-bmod-c-by-hand)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are often tricks to this if the numbers are nice enough, but even if they're not, here's a way that's not *entirely* horrible.

You already know what 439 is mod 713. What is $439^2 \mod 713$? What about $439^4$? (Hint: take your answer for $439^2$ *after* reducing it mod 713, and then square it again.) In the same way, calculate $439^8, 439^{16}, \dots, 439^{128} \mod 713$. Now just note that 233 = 128 + 64 + 32 + 8 + 1. So multiply the appropriate powers of 439 together - again, one calculation at a time, reducing mod 713 each time.

Now you should only have to do 11 calculations, and now all your numbers are 6 digits or less. Rather than impossible, it's now simply tedious. :)

By the way, one thing to notice: 713 = 23 * 31. Perhaps your calculations will be easier if you do them mod 23 and 31, then apply the [Chinese remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)?

Comment: Had we needed to compute `a^b%c` and `a>c`. Can we change `a` to `a%c` and then do `a^b%c`?

Comment: Is there any answer on ((a*b*c*d.....)^(kk^pp))%mod?

Answer (score 12):

$713=23\cdot 31$

$439 \pmod {23}=2$ and $\phi(23)=22$ and $233\equiv 13{\pmod {22}}$

So, $439^{223} {\pmod {23}} \equiv 2^{22\cdot 10 + 13}\equiv {(2^{22})}^{10}2^{13}\equiv 2^{13} {\pmod {23}}$ using [Euler's Totient Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersTotientTheorem.html).

$2^6\equiv 18  {\pmod {23}}, 2^7\equiv 36 \equiv 13$

$\implies 2^{13}\equiv 18\cdot 13=234\equiv 4 {\pmod {23}}=4+23x$ for some  integer $x$.

$439 \pmod {31}=5$ and $\phi(31)=30$ and $233\equiv 23{\pmod {30}}$

So, $439^{223} {\pmod {31}} \equiv 5^{23} {\pmod {31}}$

$5^3 \equiv 1  {\pmod {31}} \implies 5^{23}\equiv({5^3})^7 5^2\equiv 5^2{\pmod {31}}=25+31y$ for some  integer $y$.

So, we need to find $z$ such that $z=25+31y=4+23x$

Expressing as [continued fraction](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContinuedFraction.html),
$$\frac{31}{23}=1+\frac{8}{23}=1+\frac{1}{\frac{23}{8}}=1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{7}{8}}$$

$$=1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{\frac{8}{7}}}=1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{7}}}$$

So, the last but one [convergent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_%28continued_fraction%29) is $$1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{1}}=\frac{4}{3}$$

So, $23\cdot 4- 31\cdot 3=-1$

$25+31y=4+23x\implies 23x=31y+21(31\cdot 3-23\cdot 4)$
$\implies 23(x+84)=31(y+63)$
$$\implies x+84=\frac{31(y+63)}{23}$$

So, $23\mid (y+63)$ as $x+84$ is integer and $(31,23)=1$
i.e., $ 23\mid (y+69-6)\implies 23\mid (y-6) \implies y=6+23w$

So, $z=25+31y=25+31(6+31w)=713w+211 \equiv 211  {\pmod {713}}$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll ask a friend of mine to explain this to me, I'm fairly new to modulus calculation haha.

Comment: I believe you made a small mistake and set 439^223 rather than 439^233 on the 3rd line

Answer (score 7):

You can do this step by step by first computing $439^2\equiv 211 {\ \rm mod\ }713$. Then you compute $439^4\equiv 211^2 \equiv 315 {\ \rm mod\ }713$. Continue to square and reduce mod $713$ and build up a list of powers $$439^1, \qquad 439^2, \qquad 439^4 \qquad \dots \qquad 439^{128}\qquad \qquad ({\rm mod\ }713)$$
Finally, write $233$ as a sum of powers of $2$, and compute
$$439^{233}=439^{1+8+32+64+128}=439\cdot 439^8\cdot 439^{32}\cdot439^{64}\cdot 439^{128} \qquad ({\rm mod\ }713)$$
Just remember to reduce mod $713$ each time you get a product which is larger than $713$.

Answer (score 7):

You can go fast if you incrementally square:
$439^2=211 \pmod{713}$;
$211^2=315 \pmod{713}$;
$315^2=118 \pmod{713}$;
$118^2=377 \pmod{713}$;
$377^2=242 \pmod{713}$;
$242^2=98 \pmod{713}$; etc.

The last one means $439^{64}=98 \pmod{713}$;
In this way you can combine and reach 233 fast.

Ultimately  $439^{233}=211 \pmod{713}$;

Answer (score 7):

Here`s the algorithm,basically it is ***Modular exponentiation.***

```
function modular_pow(base, exponent, modulus)
  result := 1      
  while exponent > 0
      if (exponent mod 2 == 1):
         result := (result * base) mod modulus
      exponent := exponent >> 1
      base = (base * base) mod modulus
  return result
```

Also here is the working code in c++ which can work for upto 10^4 test cases,in 0.7 seconds
Also the ideone link http://ideone.com/eyLiOP

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define mod 1000000007


long long int modfun(long long int a,long long int b)
{
     long long int result = 1;
    while (b > 0)
       {
           if (b & 1)
           {
               a=a%mod;
               result = (result * a)%mod;
               result=result%mod;
           }
        b=b>>1;
        a=a%mod;
        a = (a*a)%mod;
        a=a%mod;
       }
    return result;
}
int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
        {
           long long int a,b;
           cin>>a>>b;
           if(a==0)
            cout<<0<<"\n";
           else if(b==0)
            cout<<1<<"\n";
           else if(b==1)
            cout<<a%mod<<"\n";
           else
           {
               cout<<(modfun(a,b))%mod<<"\n";
           }

        }
    return 0;
}
```