# How do I solve $(68!+68^{86} ) \mathrm{ \ mod \ }75$?

Tags: arithmetic

I feel like it's really easy and i'm just misunderstanding something. It's obvious that I need to use Wilson' and Fermat's theorems:

1. $(p-1)!≡-1\mathrm{ \ mod \ }p$
2. $a^{p-1}≡1\mathrm{ \ mod \ }p$ if $p$ does not divide $a$.

i figured i might divide $75$ (since it's not prime) into $5^2$ and $3$ and get the system:

$68!\mathrm{ \ mod \ }3+68^{86}\mathrm{ \ mod \ }3$

$68!\mathrm{ \ mod \ }5+68^{86}\mathrm{ \ mod \ }5$

Am i going in the right direction?

Comment: For the new users, please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thank you! sorry about that...

Comment: You can do it separately. First see that $68^{86}\equiv 49\bmod 75$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195634/how-do-you-calculate-the-modulo-of-a-high-raised-number).

Comment: First off, do you see that $68!$ is just an obfuscation.  $75 = 3\cdot 25$ and $3< 68$ and $25 < 68$ so $3\cdot 25\mid 68!$ so $68! \equiv 0 \pmod{75}$ and so all you need to do is solve $68^{86}\pmod {75}$.  .... And as $68$ and $75$ are relatively prime you can use Eulers theorem.  Tossing in a bit of Chinese Remainder theorem should finish it.

Comment: Thank you a lot!!! I forgot about Eulers... I appreciate it !

Comment: There are no unknowns, and therefor nothing to *solve*, you need to *calculate* something.

Comment: English is not my first language! thank you

Comment: $68! = 1 ... 3 ... 25 ... 68 = 75k$, $68^{86}=(75-7)^{86}=75m+7^{86}$, $7^4=2401=75\cdot 32+1$. $7^{86}=(7^4)^{22}\cdot 7^2$.

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches and your approach seems essentially fine, except that knowing $68^{86}
\bmod 3$ and $68^{86}
\bmod 5$ is not sufficient to obtain $68^{86}
\bmod 75$. Instead, you need $68^{86}
\bmod 3$ and $68^{86}
\bmod 25$.

Fermat's theorem says $68^{4}\equiv 1 \pmod 5$ , but you need more precise evaluation. You need to calculate $68^{4} \equiv 5a+1 \pmod {25}$ to find $68^{4k} \equiv 5ak+1 \pmod {25}$ using binomial expansion.
In this case $68^{4} \equiv 1 \pmod {25}$, so it is rather easy.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $3\mid 68! $ and $ 25\mid 68! $. So $68!\equiv 0$(mod 75).Now for the second part Fermat's little theorem is of no use as 75 is not a prime,here you need to use the Euler's totient function.You can find it [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)
.

We have $\phi (75)=(25-5)(3-2)=40$

Now by Euler's formula $68^{\phi (75)}=68^{40}\equiv 1 $(mod 75) $\Rightarrow 68^{80}\equiv 1$(mod 75).

Also $$68\equiv -7(mod 75)$$
$$\Rightarrow 68^6\equiv 7^6(mod75)$$
$$\Rightarrow 68^6\equiv 343^2\equiv 43^2\equiv 1849\equiv 49(mod 75)$$
$$\Rightarrow 68^{86}\equiv 68^{80}\times 68^6\equiv 49(mod 75)$$
So the whole thing is equivalent to 49 mod 75